# SQL query case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have an sql query which is generating a table

```
SELECT DISTINCT
concat(table.column, '.test.com) "User Login", 
concat(concat(table.columnname, ' '), lastname) "Full Name", 
'N' "Admin (Y/N)",
table.profile "Profile",
'Self' "admin", 
'Self' "user", 
FROM table.users
```

I want to add a case statement to the above query.

```
If (table.profile == admin){
admin = self;
user = null;
}
else{
admin = null;
user = self;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... it would really help to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  ...
,       case when profile = 'admin' then 'self' end as admin
,       case when coalesce(profile,'') <> 'admin' then 'self' end as user
from    table.users
```

The default value for a `case` is null, which meets your requirement.

Comment: where does the case expression go, at the end of the query?

Comment: You can use `case` where you would normally select a column, edited in answer

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Quick question what is the '<>' in your answser?

Comment: `<>` means `not equal`, it's the opposite of `=`